# word for widestly (adverb of widest)

Tags: adverbs, dictionaries, paraphrasing

I am going to paraphrase this sentence:

> It is one of the mostly used methods in ....

and I want to replace *mostly* with *widest*, but it is an adjective, not an adverb:

> It is one of the widestly! used methods in ....

Unfortunately, *widestly* does not exist. How can I write that sentence close to *widest*? (I am aware of other solutions such as *most common* etc.)

Comment: Widely: (adv.)  to a wide extent.http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/widely. Most widely used!

Comment: Shakespeare might have written *wideliest*, but the standard form is now *most widely*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts with your original sentence:

> It is one of the mostly used methods in ...

*Mostly* means that it is used more in (...) than somewhere else, but the construction of the sentence is not very nice. I'd expect to see *This method is is mostly used in ...*

I *think* you mean to say:

> It is one of the most used methods in ...

Now, you can simply add *widely* to the sentence without a problem:

> It is one of the most widely used methods in ...

Remember that you do not form comparatives or superlatives from adverbs the way you do with adjectives:

You do **not** use:

> widely, *widelier, *wideliest

But simply:

> widely, more widely, most widely

(Yes, there are words like *lovely*, *lovelier*, but *lovely* is an adjective, notwithstanding the *-ly*!)